# Silverlight 3.0 "Push" Capability information

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, push, xmpp

Does anyone have a good reference point, or can provide a summary of the enhanced "push" implementation to be changed/added in Silverlight 3.0?

I would like to compare this area to Silverlight 2.0 and to XMPP/Jabber.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main ways that you can get push functionality in Silverlight 3. The first is what you've seen at MIX using the duplex channel. The duplex channel in SL3 is essentially unchanged from the duplex channel in SL2...the main difference is that now you can add a reference to a duplex channel service within Visual Studio 2008 and the whole act of building duplex channel client/server pairs is MUCH easier.

The other way you can get push is to use a "comet server". Basically all of the servers in this family allow a client to open a socket and then continuously suck off that socket, allowing data to be pushed into the socket from the server. This is how Google and about 30 billion other Ajax sites/frameworks handle push to client. Some popular comet/push servers include Kaazing and Lightstreamer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the presentations from [Mix'09](http://sessions.visitmix.com)? [This one](http://sessions.visitmix.com/MIX09/T42F) in particular may be related.